# Prompting for user name and password in Kerberos

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, kerberos

in my application Kerberos has been enabled for security. for that in IIS settings authentication modes:

1. Basic Authentication
2. Integrated authenticated has been checked.

Application has two parts:

1. normally it should work and
2. other where it should prompt.

To prompt i am using below code

```
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.StatusCode = 401
        Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized"

        ' A authentication header must be supplied. This header can be changed to Negotiate when using keberos authentication
        Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM")

        ' Send the 401 response
        Response.End()
```

My Question in normal site it prompt me every time and how can i get it stop prompting.
whereas other where i am pushing to prompt it should work as it is.

Kindly do the needful

Answer (score 0):

NOT you should send the 401 but the server! You must provide secured urls in your web.config.